# Using subprocess.call with variables and single quotes

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use the terminal command `find path -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f '%m %N'` in a Python project. Obviously I need to supply the `path` so I've been splitting up the expression inside an array as suggested elsewhere. Currently I have `subprocess.call(['find', path, '| xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N"'])`.

The code runs but everything after `path` is ignored. In fact it throws an error `find: | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N": No such file or directory` so clearly I don't understand the way the command is being made up.

Any help would be great

EDIT:

Actually I think supplying the argument from a variable might be better. So i tried `command = 'find ' + src_dir + ' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f \'%m %N\''`

Looks OK with `print` but again when plugged into `subprocess.call(osx_command)` I get `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding shell=True

subprocess.call(['find', path, '| xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N"'], shell=True)

shell=True means executing programs through the shell, all user input passed to the program is interpreted according to the syntax and semantic rules of the invoked shell.